# bsDatePicker vs PostgreSQL: Invalid date

Tags: angular, postgresql

I'm getting this "Invalid date" error. When I set the date using the bsDatePicker, the form value shows

`"startDate": "2019-02-08T08:57:12.000Z"`

and the date input correctly says "08.02.2019" as it should.

Sending this to the server works, but after refreshing the page the input says `Invalid date` and the form value says

`"startDate": "2019-02-07T22:00:00.000+0000"`

Even seems like the day is wrong somehow.

In PostgreSQL (looking at data using pgAdmin 4) the `start_data` field says `2019-02-08`

start_date datatype in PostgreSQL is DATE, tried using timestamp too, but still the same problem.

I'll give you some code too:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="contractStart">Lepingu algus</label>
    <input id="contractStart" type="text" #startDp="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-red' }"
           class="form-control" placement="bottom" bsDatepicker formControlName="startDate">
</div>
```

I noticed if I manually write a date, i.e. `11.02.2015`, the form value of startDate will be `2015-02-10T22:00:00.000Z` and when I try to copy-paste the value into the input it becomes `Invalid date` again.

Answer (score 0):

Since it accepts only `date Object` you cant bind the value. so, when you are binding the date value do like this,

```
startDate = '2019-02-08T08:57:12.000Z';
startDate = new Date(startDate)
```

Now it binds the value to the datepicker